# Preventing Users from Performing SOQL Queries

Tags: soql, permissions, configuration

Is there a setting at the profile level to prevent users from performing SOQL queries against our Production Salesforce instance? I have disabled both "API Enabled" and "Apex REST Services", but the user still has access. The users will still need read access through the UI and we have disabled their ability to export reports already. Thanks..!

Comment: How do they perform it?

Comment: If they can't see the records the query will return empty

Comment: Queries are being made though SoqlXplorer and though a Google Sheets plugin. Our end goal is that users can do their job but not export all of our data and sell it on the internet.

Comment: If you disabled API, there shouldn't be any way to use SoqlXplorer or any sort of plugin.

Comment: @sfdcfox That's what I thought as well. I opened a case with Salesforce to investigate. I even disabled the setting, completely closed SoqlXplorer, re-logged into SoqlXplorer and I could still do queries. Maybe there is a different setting somewhere overpowering it.

Comment: @IanIepson are you sure you're logged in as the right person?

Comment: @sfdcfox Yes, just double checked. If you have the time, give the test case a try to see if the problem is isolated to my user/profile/instance. I think that will be the most valuable feedback since we are verging on sharing my screen to show you. I think screen sharing exceeds the level of support of this forum :) and there would be legal issues and NDA required for that level of support. Also, thanks for helping.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I have a non-API user I can test with in my dev org.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81018/discussion-between-sfdcfox-and-ian-iepson).

Answer (score 2):

Even though I removed the "API Enabled" flag from the profile, I missed that there was a permission set that also granted that permission. Once I removed that permission set, the user no longer had access to query though API tools.

Thanks to @sfdcfox for troubleshooting this with me.